# Android 10 app crash on EditText when text select

Tags: android, android-edittext

I my application app will crash on EditText when text enters and select that text. Otherwise it will works fine. Only problem when text gets selected by tapping on it. I have added android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants" in my xml still will not working.

Logs:

```
2020-07-06 12:15:15.256 21356-21356/com.zz.zzz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.zz.zzz, PID: 21356
    com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException: Interrupted
        at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:60)
        at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1841)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.isEnabled(AutofillManager.java:830)
        at android.widget.TextView.canRequestAutofill(TextView.java:11592)
        at android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.populateMenuWithItems(Editor.java:4017)
        at android.widget.Editor$TextActionModeCallback.onCreateActionMode(Editor.java:3961)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView$ActionModeCallback2Wrapper.onCreateActionMode(DecorView.java:2596)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionMode(DecorView.java:913)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.startActionModeForChild(DecorView.java:869)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:1008)
        at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:7339)
        at android.widget.Editor.startActionModeInternal(Editor.java:2245)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.startActionMode(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:267)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.startSelectionActionMode(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:248)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.lambda$startSelectionActionModeWithSmartSelectAnimation$0$SelectionActionModeHelper(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:302)
        at android.widget.-$$Lambda$SelectionActionModeHelper$xdBRwQcbRdz8duQr0RBo4YKAnOA.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.startSelectionActionModeWithSmartSelectAnimation(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:310)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.lambda$l1f1_V5lw6noQxI_3u11qF753Iw(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.widget.-$$Lambda$SelectionActionModeHelper$l1f1_V5lw6noQxI_3u11qF753Iw.accept(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.onPostExecute(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:998)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$TextClassificationAsyncTask.onPostExecute(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:952)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7410)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: provide code...

Comment: nameContainer = findViewById(R.id.name_container)titleTextView = nameContainer.findViewById(R.id.title_text_view)
        nameEditText = nameContainer.findViewById(R.id.edit_text)